# Any Jquery/Javascript Slider which support Right/Left/Top/Bottom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am looking for an Jquery/Javascript plugin which supports Right/Left/Top/Bottom.

I don't know the exact wording to ask the question but here is the image which help you to understand my question.

[image]

As you can see, I want to be able to display directional elements

Comment: what's exactly the purpose of those arrows? What kind of plugin are you looking for?

Comment: Slider to slide what? Large text, big image in a frame?

Comment: @F.Calderan, The purpose of these arrows are to provide value. Let say the intial values are {x:0, y:0}. Now, clicking left arrow will give you the value {x: -1, y: 0}. Now, clicking top will give the value, {x: -1, y: 1} and so on.

Comment: `var point = { x : 0, y : 0 };
$("#buttonUp").click(function() { point.y++; });
$("#buttonDown").click(function() { point.y--; });
$("#buttonLeft").click(function() { point.x--; });
$("#buttonRight").click(function() { point.x++; });`
What else do you need then?

Comment: @VisioN, Thanks looking for an existing plugin. Similar to Jquery Slider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9AtMB/
open your javascript console

html

```
<div>
    <a href="#" data-y="1" data-x="0">Up</a>
    <a href="#" data-y="-1" data-x="0">Down</a>
    <a href="#" data-x="-1" data-y="0">Left</a>
    <a href="#" data-x="1" data-y="0">Right</a>
</div>
```

js/jQuery

```
var offset =  { x: 0, y: 0 };
$('a').on('click', function(evt) {
   evt.preventDefault();
   offset.x += ~~$(this).data('x');
   offset.y += ~~$(this).data('y');
   console.log(offset);
});
```

Css (minimal)

```
div { width: 200px; height: 200px; position: relative; }
a { position: absolute; z-index: 1; }
a[data-y="1"] { top : 0; left: 50%; }
a[data-y="-1"] { bottom : 0; left: 50%; }
a[data-x="-1"] { top : 50%; left: 0; }
a[data-x="1"] { top : 50%; right: 0; }
```

The exercise to change labels with graphical arrows is left to you.

Comment: This is not working to me. See the console. It's working now thanks

Comment: I'm using FF11, it's working fine. please specify "not working"